# What is the name of the electrical connector used on Philips Pentura Mini LED?

Tags: connector

The Philips BN132C has this kind of connectors, obviously and according to the [instructions](https://www.assets.lighting.philips.com/is/content/PhilipsLighting/f3bcc52c1d5343078478a76100d3996f) to connect up to 10 of these lights to each other:

[image]
[image]

It seems to be possible to purchase cable connectors with the product number BN132Z (see [datasheet](https://www.assets.signify.com/is/content/PhilipsLighting/fp910503910166-pss-global)), but nothing mentions the name of the connectors.

[image]

The reason why I am looking for it is, because I would prefer to plug the light in instead of a wire installation. Another reason is, I bought the BN132C, which seems to have no possibility to attach any wires to, and somehow cannot purchase the BN133C which does have external wires according to the [datasheet](https://www.assets.signify.com/is/content/PhilipsLighting/fp910503910166-pss-global).

[image]

Comment: Looks like a standard figure 8 cable would likely fit. You didn't provide any measurements.

Comment: You are right; although it is very very tight, it does fit. Thanks a lot, @Passerby!

Comment: you can shave it a bit to fit with a knife carefully. And not sure if it's polarized so make sure that you match/don't twist the connection.